# How to solve "Uncaught TypeError: restVar.reload is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My url is like this : http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox/detail/58c508e9607a1d16f0006b3f

My function javascript is like this :

```
reloadMessage() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var vars = location.href;
        var arrVars = vars.split("/");
        var lastVar = arrVars.pop();
        var lastVar = arrVars.pop();
        var restVar = arrVars.join("/");
        restVar.reload(true);
    }, 1500);
}
```

I want when call reloadMessage function, it will reload page to url :

```
http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox
```

But it does not work

There exist error like this :

> Uncaught TypeError: restVar.reload is not a function

How can I solve it?

**Update :**

If I do : `console.log(restVar)`, the result :

http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox

When call reloadMessage function, I want it will reload page /  url : http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you don't show us what `restVar` is, how it's initialized, how the function above is called, etc., etc.?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I had update my question

Comment: The **question** still doesn't tell us anything about how `restVar` is declared or initialized, or how `reloadMessage` is called.The full content of your question must be **in** your question ([as text wherever possible](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247)), not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code that declares restVar:

```
var restVar = arrVars.join("/");
```

Returns an array, which wouldn't have 'reload()' available as a function.  After you get your new URL, you might try window.location (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Comment: Great. It works. I try this : `window.location.assign(restVar);`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `reload` for this. Just change location:

```
function reloadMessage() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var vars = location.href;
        var arrVars = vars.split("/");
        arrVars.pop();
        arrVars.pop();
        location = arrVars.join("/");
    }, 1500);
}
```

Comment: When call reloadMessage function, it does not call url : http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox